# Is there a packet sniffer for Windows Mobile?

Tags: http, networking, windows-mobile, packet-sniffers

I'm looking for a tool along the lines of Fiddler, or better yet Wireshark, that would run on a Windows Mobile 6.1 device.

I have an app which calls some webservices on one of our servers, and I want to make sure it it going out to the proper address.

Comment: Do you have to run Wireshark on the device itself to do that? We usually just hook it up to the network on the nearest switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I want to test something like that I connect the device to my PC and use ActiveSync.  The mobile device then can send all of it's internet requests through the PC.  Wireshark can then be used to sniff the traffic coming in and out of the device.  Works good and is a stable approach.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to search for this myself. There are a few of these out there but most are old and have not been updated recently. If you are looking for one to sniff the WiFi traffic it should be simple and Google should provide something suitable. However the issue I ran into (and could not get around with about 3hrs invested) was trying to sniff the EV-DO/Cell data connection. Seems the cell radio uses a different type of network driver then the WiFi connections on a WinMo device. Not much of an answer, sorry, but I figured I would share my experiences.

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental version of [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm) for windows CE.
Maybe it will work for you.